# How to access a child's dataset from the parent/root node when clicked anywhere on the body element - Js/ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent container that has few nodes. the tree structure looks like:

```
    <div class="main">
       <div class="child1">some content1</div>
       <div class="child2">some content4</div>
       <p></p>
       <span></span>
       <div class="child3" data-mask="child3-content">some content5</div> // I want to access this child using the data set property attached to it.
       <div class="child4">some content13</div>
</div>
```

When I click on the body element, I want to access certain child node when clicked using the dataset `data-mask` and if this property exsists I want to return `null`

eg:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("click", this.onBodyClick);
  }

onBodyClick(eve) {
const rc = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); 
/*this will give me the entire dom node.
   
    <div class="main">
       <div class="child1">some content1</div>
       <div class="child2">some content4</div>
       <p></p>
       <span></span>
       <div class="child3" data-mask="child3-content">some content5</div> // I want to access this child using the data set property attached to it.
       <div class="child4">some content13</div>
</div>
 */

 /* From here I want to search for the below child
    <div class="child3" data-mask="child3-content">some content5</div>
*/

//Here I'm not sure how to access use `eve` to get that node using the dataset.

}
```

any ideas around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the onClick listener to that main class div and make a function call it there, that will give you the event from that you can get the element and attribute value.

```
handleClick(e){
  console.log(e.currentTarget) // will give you the clicked element
  
  console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-mask")) // will give you 
  the value of data-mask attribute
}

<div class="main" onClick={(e)=>handleClick(e)}>
<div class="child1">some content1</div>
   <div class="child2">some content4</div>
   <p></p>
   <span></span>
   <div class="child3" data-mask="child3-content">some content5</div>
</div>
```